# mod_slotmem.so: undefined symbol: apr_shm_remove

Tags: apache, jboss, httpd.conf, mod-jk, mod-cluster

I am trying to create a jboss cluster as mentioned in the link below..

```
[https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/AS7+Cluster+Howto][1]
```

I was able to complete upto the installation of apache httpd. But, faced a error when i tried to load the following modules in the httpd.conf file.

```
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so
```

The error is as follows,

```
Cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_slotmem.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_slotmem.so: undefined symbol: apr_shm_remove
```

Any information on fixing this error will be really helpful...

My JBoss Version is JBoss AS 7.1 and Apache Version is Apache/2.0.65

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Did you load it properly in the config?

`LoadModule cluster_slotmem_module modules/mod_cluster_slotmem.so`

It is called `cluster_slotmem_module`, not `slotmem_module`.